# Recording speaker output at 100% volume despite turning them down - may need to uncouple application volume from output device volume

Tags: windows-10, audio-recording, volume-mixer, obs-studio

I am trying to record audio only of a webcast running in a Chrome tab on Open Broadcaster Software Studio. I am using a Windows 10 laptop, with nothing plugged in, so laptop speakers and microphone only.

My understanding is that the default behaviour of OBS is to record at 100% volume regardless of the speaker settings. However, when I try to record the webcast the volume of the recording changes with the speaker slider, and mutes when I mute the speakers. I want to be able to record in the background with speakers muted or turned down.

If I right click and open Volume Mixer (Conexant ISST Audio), I can see that the volumes of the individual programs are tied to the output device. Although I can see OBS Studio as a separate option, I cannot make it louder than the speakers.

I have installed EarTrumpet, which is a replacement volume mixer. When I open the EarTrumpet volume mixer, there is no connection between the volume sliders, so I could technically set OBS to 100% and speakers to a lower volume.

However, EarTrumpet appears to be connected to the Windows Volume Mixer - I have tried setting Windows Volume Mixer Speakers to 100% and then controlling the levels with EarTrumpet, but lowering the volume in EarTrumpet just lowers the volume in the Windows mixer, which in turn lowers the volume going to OBS.

Is there a simple way for me to record at 100% volume despite hearing a lower volume from my speakers?

(I am not tied to OBS or EarTrumpet, but I would prefer free software.)

Comment: If I read your question right, I believe Audacity will give you the flexibility you're looking for. https://www.audacityteam.org/

Comment: I use EarTrumpet on my main PC and I call it more of a "advanced" Windows Volume Mixer, because, for example, you can set where an app will output (volume is irrelevant in this situation), dunno if it's appropriate for your scenario.

Comment: I have used Goldwave for about 20 years and I have never experienced the problem you describe. It is paid but they have a fully functional evaluation version that may get you through this project. Also, it's only a 1-time 45$ charge. https://www.goldwave.com/